# How to overwrite an input's default value (from WP get_terms()) using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I have a form with an input field with a value that is pulled from a a WP `get_terms()` array, like so:

```
    <?php $location = sanitize_text_field($_GET['location']);

    if($location) {
        $matching_locations = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'job_location',
            'fields' => 'slugs',
            'name__like' => $location
        ));
    };
    if($matching_locations) : ?>
        <section class="job-search__side-bar-location">
            <h2 class="job-search__side-bar-title">Location</h2>
            <div class="job-search__sider-bar-location-row">
                <label class="job-search__side-bar-location"><?php echo ucwords($matching_locations[0]); ?></label>
                <input type="hidden" name="location" class="job-search__side-bar-location" id="location_side-bar" value="<?php echo $matching_locations[0]; ?>" readonly />
                <input id="remove-location" class="job-search__side-bar-location-delete" value="&#x2715" />
            </div>
        </section>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Underneath the `location` input, I have a second input with an id of `remove-location`, which has a jQuery `click` method assigned to it that is supposed to assign an empty string as the `value` of the `location` input and then resubmit the form:

```
    $('#remove-location').click(function() {
        $('#location_side-bar').val("");
        $('#sidebar-search').submit();
    })
```

However, when I click on the `remove-location` input, the form is submitted again with the `location` same value from the tax query. Is there any way around this? I'd like for the form to retain the `location` value in all cases, except for when the `remove-location` input is clicked.

I've added an image to help illustrate what I'm aiming for:

[image: Screenshot of inputs]

Comment: you probably want to prevent the default action of your click otherwise the form will be submitted before you remove the value - https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: @Pete I don't think this is the issue, as the form (in its current state) should only ever submit when this particular input is clicked, so I don't think there's any default behaviour to prevent (unless I'm mistaken)? I've tried adding the event.preventDefault anyway to check, but sadly no difference